# How do I understand Subject-Verb inversion?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement, inversion

I know Subject-Verb inversion is the format to form a question.

When we start a question with 'What',

> What it means? -improper 
>  What does it mean? -proper

But then, if we start the question with 'Who', where is the subject? Is 'Who' subject?

> Who lives there? -looks much better than 
>  Who does live there?

I would appreciate Native speakers' help in understanding Subject-Verb inversion.

Comment: Have you considered that *mean* as used is a transitive verb, and *live* as used is an intransitive verb?

Comment: Does it affect the question? If yes, how?

Comment: In the first question, *what* isn't the subject; it's the object.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to understand this problem is to make an *in situ* question. For an *in situ* question we don't move the *wh-* word to the front of the sentence. We leave it in the same place it would be in a normal sentence:

- You gave it to *who*?
- You did *what*?
- You went there *when*?
- You did it *how*?
- *Who* ate it?

In these in situ questions we do not need any subject auxiliary inversion. Notice also that the question words there are in the same position in those sentences as they will be in the answers:

- I gave it to ***Bob***.
- I did ***this***.
- I went there ***yesterday***.
- I did it ***like this***.
- ***Bob*** ate it.

Now if we make a normal question notice that the *wh-* word moves to the front of the sentence *and* we need subject auxiliary inversion:

- Who **did you** gave it to?
- What **did you** do?
- When **did you** go there?
- How **did you** do it?

I only did the first four questions above. Notice that in the fifth example, the *in situ* question was:

- *Who* ate it?

and the answer was:

- ***Bob*** ate it.

Now in this in situ question, the *wh-* word is already at the front of the sentence, because the thing/person we are asking about is the subject of the verb *ate*. Because we do not need to move the *wh-* word, we do not need to use subject auxiliary inversion here. The normal question and the *in situ* question are the same.
It does not matter if the *wh-* word is *who* or *what* or *which* or *whose*. If the *wh-* word does not need to move because it is already at the front of the sentence, then we do not need subject auxilairy inversion.

- *Who* ate it?
- *What* happened?
- *Which* person said that?
- *Whose* girlfriend kissed you?

We can see that these words were already at the front of the sentence when we see the answers:

- ***Bob*** ate it.
- ***This*** happened.
- ***That*** person said it.
- ***Bob's*** girlfriend kissed me.

**The Original Poster's question**

> *Who* lives there?

In this sentence, the word *who* is the subject of *lives*. We do not need to move it to the front to make the question. Notice that in the answer, the name of the person comes in the same place as the *wh-* word:

- ***Bob*** lives there.

Because the question word is already at the front of the sentence, we do not need subject auxiliary inversion.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Answer (score 1):

The difference, as another commenter said, is whether the question word ("what", "who") is also the *subject* of the sentence, for example:

> Who lives here?

In that sentence, "who" is the subject, and it stands for some person, as in the answer "Jack lives here." So "who" gets replaced by "Jack". But in this sentence:

> Who *do you* know here?

the subject is 'you' - you are someone who may know other people here. Then you need the auxiliary verb "do".

It's the same with 'what':

> What lives in the river?

"What" is the subject of the sentence. The answer might be "Fish live in the river", so "what" gets replaced with "fish". However, in the sentence:

> What *does this* mean?

The subject is 'this'. Note that this is very close to the way you would make a question like "does this mean anything?".

When you want to use a question word in a sentence that's not a question, then the auxiliary verbs are dropped:

- Tell me what *this means*, not "tell me what does this mean"
- Tell me who *you know* here, not "tell me who do you know here"
- Tell me what lives in the river (no change, there was no auxiliary verb)
- Tell me who lives here (no change, there was no auxiliary verb)

Answer (score 0):

In questions of the type

- Who are you?
- Who goes there?

with who in subject case or nominative there is no inversion nor  use of to do. Who is the subject. It is a special type of question.