# Usage of indirect questions

Tags: word-order

Is it right to say: "Could you tell me how many students there are in classes?"
                 or "Could you tell me how many students are there in classes?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is correct? - "Guess, what it is?" or "Guess, what is it?"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46959/which-is-correct-guess-what-it-is-or-guess-what-is-it) Also [How do I understand Subject-Verb inversion?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52074/how-do-i-understand-subject-verb-inversion)

Comment: With subordinate interrogative clauses there's normally no subject-auxiliary inversion, so your first example is correct. It means: "Can you tell me the answer to the question 'How many students are there in class?"'